# Searching for duplicate values in a multiple 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I am figuring to get a method to search the duplicated parts in a 2D array in Python.

Taking the below array for example:

```
Array1 = [[1, 7], [2, 7], [3, 7], [4, 7], [5, 7], [6, 7], [7, 7]]

Array2 = [[5, 8], [5, 7], [5, 6], [5, 5], [5, 4]]

Array3 = [[1, 7], [2, 7], [3, 7], [4, 7], [5, 7], [6, 7], [7, 7]]

ArrayN = [......]
```

the result I would like to get is like this:

```
Array_result = [[5,7]]
```

Is there any method that can automatically search the duplicated areas and save the coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do so, converting lists to [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

```
data = [
    [[1, 7], [2, 7], [3, 7], [4, 7], [5, 7], [6, 7], [7, 7]],
    [[5, 8], [5, 7], [5, 6], [5, 5], [5, 4]],
    [[1, 7], [2, 7], [3, 7], [4, 7], [5, 7], [6, 7], [7, 7]],
]

arr_result = set(tuple(x) for x in data[0])
for arr in data[1:]:
    arr_result.intersection_update(tuple(x) for x in arr)
print(arr_result)  # {(5, 7)}
```

As each list contains sub-lists, they must be converted into tuples, because lists are unhashable.

We convert the first list to a `set()`, then for each list in `data`, we intersect the set and the list using [`intersection_update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection_update).

---

Using list comprehension:

```
arr_result = set.intersection(*[{tuple(x) for x in arr} for arr in data])
print(arr_result)  # {(5, 7)}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Cubix48* solution using list comprehension should be preferred, use the below just as reference for other problems.

---

Using collections:

```
from collections import Counter

array_list = [[str(x) for x in array] for array in [Array1, Array2, Array3]]
c = Counter()
for item in array_list:
    c.update(item)

repeated_items = [eval(item) for item in dict(c).keys() if c[item] == len(array_list)]
```